# Superset display dynamic content from query (markdown)

Tags: apache-superset

I would like to display a chart in a dashboard displaying text. The text value is retrieved from a query.

*e.g.*
I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT MAX(update_date) FROM my_data_tbl
```

I would like to create a box (inside the dashboard) like this one:
[image]

I've tried with the 'Markdown Chart' but i don't understand how to dynamical push data into the component

Answer (score 3):

I don't think getting data into the markdown "chart" is currently possible. The markdown is more for adding text to a dashboard.

One hacky way to do this could be to use the Table chart type. Values in a table can use html. You'll most likely have to do some awkward string manipulation using SQL to get html into your query results, but it works.